# Python project structure puts tests folder in root of site_packages

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a project with the folder structure

```
/top_folder/
|__README.txt
|__setup.py
|__aikif/
|   |__config.py
|   |__run_agents.py
|   |__lib/
|   |   |__cls_goal.py
|   |   |__cls_plan.py
|   |__web_app/   
|       |__page_about.py
|__tests/
    |__test_goal.py
    |__run_tests.py
```

which works fine on github and appears to be the standard folder structure, but when I try to package this as follows

```
setup(
    name='aikif',
    version='0.0.2',
    packages=['aikif', 'tests', 'aikif.lib', 'aikif.web_app'],
```

It installs a tests folder in the root of python\lib\site_packages, which surely would also be used by other packages.

What is the proper way to do this - do I need to move the tests folder into the aikif project folder or is there an issue with setup.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my projects, I do not package the test folder, as I believe the tests are used only by programmers and the packaged version is built for users.

Do you really need to package the test folder?

Comment: Thank you - so in my above example I would also exclude the root 'aikif' package seeing it only contained setup.py

Comment: You should exclude the '/top_folder/' folder, but not the 'aikif' one, as it contains config.py, run_agent.py...